# Getting this exception : FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 5:45 Expression not in GROUP BY key '" "'

Tags: hive

**Getting this exception :  FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 5:45 Expression not in GROUP BY key '" "' when trying to execute the below hive query. What is wrong in the query?**

```
Create table Daily_Summary_Table AS
select Dt,Day_Of_Week,Mon, Yr,Weekend, Total_Trip_Count,Total_Trip_Fare,Total_Trip_Miles,Total_Trip_Duration,
sum(mult_fare)/count(*) as avg_wt_trip_fare,sum(mult_miles)/count(*) as avg_wt_trip_miles, sum(mult_dur) /count(*) as avg_wt_trip_dur
from
(select to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(split(trip_start_time, " ")[0], 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) as Dt,
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(split(trip_start_time, " ")[0], 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'u') as Day_Of_Week,
from_unixtime(to_unix_timestamp(split(trip_start_time, " ")[0], 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'MMM') as Mon,
year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(split(trip_start_time, " ")[0], 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))) as Yr,
Weekend, 
count(*) as Total_Trip_Count,
count(round(trip_fare)), as Total_Trip_Fare,
count(round(trip_miles)) as Total_Trip_Miles,
count(round(trip_seconds/60)) as Total_Trip_Duration,
count(taxi_id_int)*round(trip_fare) mult_fare, 
count(taxi_id_int)*round(trip_miles) mult_miles, 
count(taxi_id_int)*round(trip_seconds/60) mult_dur
from chicago_taxis.taxi_trip_details_weekend_encoded_sharmi) T
group by to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(split(trip_start_time, " ")[0], 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')),
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(split(trip_start_time, " ")[0], 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'u'),
from_unixtime(to_unix_timestamp(split(trip_start_time, " ")[0], 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'MMM'),
year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(split(trip_start_time, " ")[0], 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))) ,
Weekend, 
round(trip_fare), 
round(trip_miles), 
round(trip_seconds/60);
```

Comment: as the error says, some expressions in select are not in the group by expression

Comment: @mck I know, but which key i am not able to understand. I have however not included the count fields.

Comment: Subquery T coontains aggregation without group by.  Main query contains aggregation with group by which seems should be in the subquery T

Comment: @leftjoin So I modified the query to include the group by inside subquery, now I get this error  FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'as'

Comment: Can anyone pls help?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue got fixed using the below query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Daily_Summary_Table
STORED AS ORC 
AS
Select Date,
Day_Of_Week,
Month,
Year,
Weekend,
sum(mult_fare)/count(*) as avg_wt_trip_fare,sum(mult_miles)/count(*) as avg_wt_trip_miles, sum(mult_dur) /count(*) as avg_wt_trip_dur
from(
select to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(split(trip_start_time, " ")[0], 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) Date,
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(split(trip_start_time, " ")[0], 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'u') Day_Of_Week,
from_unixtime(to_unix_timestamp(split(trip_start_time, " ")[0], 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'MMM') Month,
year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(split(trip_start_time, " ")[0], 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))) Year,
Weekend, 
count(trip_id_int),
count(round(trip_fare)),
count(round(trip_miles)),
count(round(trip_seconds/60)),
count(taxi_id_int)*round(trip_fare) mult_fare, 
count(taxi_id_int)*round(trip_miles) mult_miles, 
count(taxi_id_int)*round(trip_seconds/60) mult_dur
from chicago_taxis.taxi_trip_details_weekend_encoded_sharmi
where trip_fare is not null and trip_miles is not null and trip_seconds is not null
group by to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(split(trip_start_time, " ")[0], 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')),
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(split(trip_start_time, " ")[0], 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'u'),
from_unixtime(to_unix_timestamp(split(trip_start_time, " ")[0], 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'MMM'),
year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(split(trip_start_time, " ")[0], 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))),
Weekend,
round(trip_fare), 
round(trip_miles), 
round(trip_seconds/60)) T
group by Date,
Day_Of_Week,
Month,
Year,
Weekend;
```